# Error on Accounts after install Brazilian Language pack

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'm using **Sugar CE 6.5.17** and everything works fine when using the **English language (default)**.

I downloaded and installed the **Brazilian language pack**:

> http://www.sugarforge.org/frs/download.php/9578/SugarCE-6.5.3.zip

But when I list the Accounts and select one Account to see it, I get an empty page on Chrome and a text `null` on IE.

I put the loglevel to debug, but nothings wrong. It's very strange, because this only happens when logged in using PT-BR.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your web servers error logs, on a Linux system it might be somewhere like /var/log/apache2/error_log although you might have a seperate PHP only error log set up in your php.ini file.  You could also edit your php.ini file and turn on 'display_errors' and this will print out errors on the screen.  Make sure you turn it back off after all is fixed though.  What you are probably going to find is a fatal error in a language file somewhere.  My guess from my tests would be a custom language file maybe.

I can tell you that I just spun up both a 6.5.3ce and a 6.5.17ce and loaded the above language file on both and got no errors in accounts on either one.  So it doesn't look like there is an issue with the language file itself.

Kenneth Brill
Developer Support Engineer
SugarCRM, Inc.
St. Louis, MO